# pulse audio not playing sound in i3wm / Arch

Tags: linux, audio, arch-linux, pulse-audio

I am using Arch Linux with i3wm. Before, I was using Gnome, and audio was working fine. However, after switching to i3wm, sound is not coming out of my speakers.

I installed `pavucontrol`, and the visualizer bars appear to be reacting (bouncing up and down) correctly when I have sound playing, e.g. a video playing in Firefox.

Output of `pactl stat`:

```
Server String: /run/user/1000/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 32
Server Protocol Version: 32
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 6
Tile Size: 65472
User Name: daveliu
Host Name: latitude_arch
Server Name: pulseaudio
Server Version: 11.1
Default Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
Default Source: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
Cookie: b963:c6e8
```

Also, I added my user to the `audio` group and that didn't help either. There does not appear to be any indication that my sound card or pulseaudio is having any issues; the only thing is no sound is playing.

What do I need to get sound to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you get output using `pactl info` PulseAudio is running and because it worked in GNOME before a permission or driver problem can most likely be ruled out.

In `pavucontrol` you can check the tab "Output Devices" if your speakers or headphones are shown (and or plugged in) or have been muted. If you set the volume regulater to 100% PulseAudio should unmute and set the Master Volume, the PCM and the Device volume back to 100% as well.

You can also unmute and set this with `alsamixer` (you may have to select the sound card first).

Hope this helps, but since audio problems can have a number of reasons, I'd suggest you also take a look at the [PulseAudio/Troubleshooting](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting) page in the Archlinux Wiki.